# Multiple sites in one Piranha-CMS

Tags: piranha-cms

I'm planning to run multiple sites in one instance of Piranha-CMS. The sites are small (< 20 pages) and all have their own layout.

According to this line in the documentation i have to create multiple IIS websites: 
"A note on caching: As most meta-data entities are memory cached on the server side to ensure scalability it is neccessary to create a site in IIS for each site in the manager interface."

Is this still true for the current release, 2.2.1? If so, is their a workaround so i can still use multiple Piranha sites under one IIS-site, for example by using unique page types for each site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved and the documentation should be updated. In previous version there was a bug that caused the cache-errors on the start pages of the different navigation trees.

Regards

Håkan

Comment: Hello,   we have a few questions regarding the multisite implementation. We have a need to have a single IIS site with several bindings(different subdomains). There is currently the concept of site in the Piranha CMS. Can you indicate how we may implement the following? - Assign a site created in the CMS to a binding on IIS - Make sure that the pages created under a site is accessible only via a specific binding(which has been assigned to a CMS site)...

Kind Regards...

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how it's set up. For each site within Piranha CMS you can assign one, or several hostnames. These hostnames can be a subdomain or a completely different domain. In the latest version you can also assign a suffix foreaxample mysite.com/anothersite and all request going to that will be remapped to the site.